# Goal conversion issue - var modification

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'REMOVED']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'REMOVED']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var headString = "<li><a onclick='goog_report_conversion('REMOVED'); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Phone Call', 'Clicked', 'REMOVED']);' href='tel:REMOVED'>REMOVED</a> / REMOVED</li>";
jQuery('.primary-nav-menu li:first').before(headString);
jQuery(document).on('click', jQuery('#head_link'), function(e){
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Phone Call', 'Clicked', 'REMOVED']);
});
});
</script>
```

According to client, there are "too many false positives". This is also an explanation I got: "There is no double quotes " in the code. but it renders that way perhaps because of the var string the ' needs to have special characters to be rendered correctly?"

Is it possible to get "get that same line in the header WITHOUT a var string"? I am not JS developer so I have no ideas on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

use \ to escape the double quotes.

```
var headString = "<li><a onclick=\"goog_report_conversion('REMOVED'); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Phone Call', 'Clicked', 'REMOVED']);\" href='tel:REMOVED'>REMOVED</a> / REMOVED</li>";
```

Comment: Would this work? jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.primary-nav-menu li:first').before("here comes my HTML");. In other words, I'd remove var and would put html directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something more like:

```
var li = $('<li />');
var a = $('<a />', {
    href:"PHONE NUMBER"
    }.text("PHONE NUMBER").appendTo(li);
li.appendTo($('.primary-nav-menu li:first'));

a.on('click', function(e) {
    goog_report_conversion('REMOVED');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Phone Call', 'Clicked', 'REMOVED']);
});
```